# How to custom user models in django 1.5

Tags: python, django

As we all know, django provide an strong User and Authenticate app.

as usually, there is two way to custom the user

1. use OneToOneField way . we can define a model profile which keep some user information fields. we also can use get_profile method to get the profile. but,there is a problem, if
   we get the user profile, we must join the data table. some code demo:

   ```
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   class Profile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   ```
2. use AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin . we can custom the user by change the  AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin in django--1.5, and must define the UserAdmin.the document:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

I am very confused and do not know which way is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do is add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to settings with path to custom user class, which extends either AbstractBaseUser (more customizable version) or AbstractUser.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        u = self.create_user(username,
                        password=password,
                        date_of_birth=date_of_birth
                    )
        u.is_admin = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
                        verbose_name='email address',
                        max_length=255
                    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Comment: I konw this way。  I have no idea which way is better。

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this now since Django 1.5 is with [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user), setting [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to your user model.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to be confused. The docs you link to are correct: you should extend AbstractBaseUser.

Also, you should upgrade to version 1.6.